# Create website to control RaspberryPi remotely

Tags: gpio, pi-2, sensor, web-server

I wanted to home automation for a long time. Basically what I want is a website through which I can control my raspberry pi GPIO pins and also read and display data from them on my website.

I will have a button on my website to control the light of my room and also display temperature from a temperature sensor connected to GPIO. But the problem is that I don't want to host a web server on the RPi itself, instead I want the rpi to connect to a web server or website on another machine and since I am learning Django, is it possible by it?

What more things should I learn? And, how will be the basic idea to implement it?

Comment: It's possible, but doing it has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi; if you think of it as "I need to connect from a Raspberry Pi to my Acme X567 server" you will waste a lot of time.  You need to connect to a web server using python and send it information.  Note that for development purposes, it actually doesn't matter if the server is running on a different machine or not.  Anyway, the place for general (and networking, and web oriented) python programming is our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) .